# Stackoverflow error on using twitter bootstrap attributes in element tag

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using the latest version of Thymeleaf with Spring Boot project. I run into a very strange issue where I'm given a stackoverflow error when I use `autofocus` or `required` attributes in an element tag. I'm using the latest version of `Twitter Bootstrap` project. In my project I'm using: Spring Security, ThymeLeaf, and Twitter Bootstrap. The configuration is done using Java Configuration. Below is the code that produces stackoverflow. If I remove `autofocus` and `required` attributes the application runs fine.

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace to your question. Your HTML snippet doesn't give any clue to what went wrong.

Comment: Since it's a stackoverflow the trace message is long. I have created a GIST which is available at the below address: https://gist.github.com/5db/47a5b163fd8054d39a81

Comment: Have you tried using XML compliant tags like `required="required"` and `autofocus="autofocus"`?

Comment: Yes, that works. It looks like a bug in ThymeLeaf library.

Comment: It's not a bug. If you read the manual, Thymeleaf requires XML compliance.

Answer (score 1):

Thymleaf requires XML compliance. This means closing tags, and attributes with values. You can use:

```
required="required" autofocus="autofocus"
```

Adding the answer as Bart's response helped me.